# Clip-path is not working in firefox despite being compatible (aparently?)

Tags: css, cross-browser, clip-path

I can't get clip path to work of firefox. As far as i can find it is compatible, although i can't figure out why its not working and as far as i can tell this isn't a very common problem. It works fine on chrome. Is there something I'm missing?

```
#rectangle {
    transform-origin: top left;
    padding-right:200px;
    top:70px;
    -webkit-clip-path:inset(0px 100% 0px 0px);
    clip-path:inset(0px 100% 0px 0px);
}
```

Comment: http://greensock.com/forums/topic/12272-animating-svg-masks-clip-path-not-working-in-firefox/

Comment: I have just created one yesterday, with the same syntax and indeed, it does not work at all in FF. I have also tried the "mask" syntax, that one does not even work properly in Chrome.Clip path is simply not yet fit for use.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem. If you scroll to the bottom of the Clip-Path MDN page  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
you can see that even though inset is used in some of the example markup of the article itself, Mozilla (Gecko) does not support inset.

The following is the footnote on its progress...
[5] This feature was implemented behind the preference layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled, defaulting to false, since Gecko 47 (Firefox 47.0 / Thunderbird 47.0 / SeaMonkey 2.44). Basic shapes except inset() got implemented in bug 1075457, inset() got implemented in bug 1246762. Since Gecko 53 (Firefox 53.0 / Thunderbird 53.0 / SeaMonkey 2.50) the preference defaulted to true on Nightly and Developer Edition (bug 1303654), since Gecko 54 (Firefox 54.0 / Thunderbird 54.0 / SeaMonkey 2.51) it also defaults to true on Beta and Stable releases bug 1247229.

One possible workaround is using polygon instead of inset to create a rectangular clip. Hope this helps, and possibly other people can provide better answers here as I am still curious and figuring workarounds. Perhaps there is a polyfill?